# I need to check wheter record exists in Oracle SQL DB

Tags: sql, node.js, angular, oracle

I am doing the following query with NodeJS in an Oracle SQL database

```
export async function getGuard(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
    const conn = await connect();
    let { document} = req.params;
    const result = await conn.execute(
        `
      select ideide 
      from basdat.siide, basdat.siideead
      where idecod='${document}'
      and idecod=ideeadcod
      and ideeadact='S'
      `

    );
    console.log(result.rows[0][0].length);
    if (result.rows[0][0].length > 0) {
        return res.json(result.rows[0][0]);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ text: "Registro no existe" });
    }
}
```

I am trying to validate that if that record that I am sending you does not exist, it can generate an action in an Angular Registration form

```
this.documentreg = this.forma.value.document
console.log(this.documentreg);
this._usuarioService.getdocument(this.forma.value.document)
  .subscribe( resp => { 
    this.documentser = resp;
    if (this.documentreg == this.documentser) {
      console.log('Are not equal');

    } else {
      console.log('Are equal ');

    }
  }, err => {
       console.log(err);
  }


);
```

When the registration exists, the IF was executed but when I pass a document that does not exist, it is not giving me anything back, I did not even execute the IF

PD: The Oracle database I only use to check if the document exists, I'm not storing anything in it

Comment: In Oracle if the data doesn't exists, it doesn't return anything. If you just want to check does document exists, use count. So, if a document does not exists it will return count of zero. select count(ideide)...

Comment: If the query returns no row, you will get an empty `result`, so this test `result.rows[0][0].length > 0` is probably wrong. And BTW check if you are using *bind variables*;)

Comment: Here's the doc on using bind variables: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#bind